# How to calculate Heroku dyno usage?

Tags: heroku

I'm new to Heroku and planning to upload all my applications there until i made some research about package pricing and found out that free apps get around 550-1000 dyno hours per month and for standard package 25$-50$ per dyno per month, now here lies the question.

Does this mean that standard Package X1 for instance if I consumed 1000 dyno hours per month i will billed 25($/dyno) x 1000 dyno = 25,000$ per month?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Dyno type has a different [price](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/usage-and-billing) which is what you **pay every month**, for example $25 for standard-1x. That's what you are billed every month (no more).

The hours come in place when you select a Free Dyno:

- the first 550 hrs are free, after that the Dyno stops working (next month you get the same quota and the Dyno can restart)
- you can extend to 1000 (free) hrs if you register a valid Credit Card